# How to transfer jar from azure pipeline to ADLS or DBFS?

Tags: azure, scala, azure-devops, databricks

I am using azure pipeline to build scala code, I want the jar to be copied to another location in adls or dbfs. How can I achieve that? I tried using publish build artifacts but not sure if it will work?